# Updating repository with Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm on a PC doing a project for a company, they have given me a link to their repo

```
https://companyname.beanstalkapp.com/app_name
```

Is it possible for me to update code in this url using Tortoise SVN?  I tried once using the export option  in Tortoise SVN and the url above and after several minutes a message said done but the code has not been updated.

Comment: All depends if their server allows external Read/Write with your credentials

Comment: Yes I have read/write permission.

Comment: Your question makes it look like you have no idea whatsoever how to use SVN. "export" is not the command to change code in a repository. "export" is also not the command to get code on your machine for modification. "export" is to get an archived copy of the code at a specific revision. You may have wanted "checkout" or "update" or "commit" instead. These are all VERY basic operations. You should read up on how to use your tool before you start trying commands blindly without knowing what they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.com). If you go through the first two chapters, (and it shouldn't take you longer than a few hours at the most), you'll get a complete rundown of Subversion and how to use it. If you had ever use version control before, you can probably run through the first four chapters in an hour or two.

Subversion is extremely simple and there are some very basic concepts you need to know.

The *URL* you are given is the address to the Subversion repository. Don't be fooled by the `https://` prefix. Subversion has multiple ways you can talk to the main repository, and `httpd` is one of the most popular. It's not a webpage. It's an address of your Subversion repo. It could have been just as easily started with `svn://`.

You *checkout* from the master repo to a local working directory on your system. This is ***your*** working directory. You're not suppose to share it. If someone else needs to modify a file or two, they checkout to their own *working directory*.

You *checkout* the code to your local machine, make your changes, and when you're done, you *commit* your changes back to the master repository. People will be able to see what changes you made and why you made those changes.

Subversion was designed to be used by multiple *clients*. This is how you communicate with the repository. For example, if you use VisualStudio, you can use the VisualStudio Subversion client. If you are on Linux, you can use the Nautilus client thats built into the Nautilus file browser. You can use any client you choose. Unlike other version control systems, Subversion was designed to be *client agnostic*.

TortoiseSVN is a client that works through Windows Explorer. Open Windows Explorer. Make a folder on your machine to store your working copies. Then, if you have TortioiseSVN installed, you should be able to right click on that folder, and go to "SVN Checkout". When you do, you'll see a dialog box pop up to allow you to select the repository and browse through it. Under the URL of the repository, put `https://companyname.beanstalkapp.com/app_name`. Then click on the box with the three dots to the right.

This will allow you to "explore" the repository. You want to do that because I suspect there might be a `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches`. You probably want trunk. Find the directory you want to checkout, and right click on that new folder and select "Checkout". Subversion will checkout the complete project. You can then use whatever tools you want (I recommend Notepad++) to edit the files on your system.

Once you've modified all of the files you need, go back to the root folder of your working copy, right click on it, and select "Commit". You give a description of what changes you've made and why, and that's it, you've made your changes.

Again, read the Subversion book. It's fast and simple and will get you up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Beanstalk's docs, `companyname.beanstalkapp.com/app_name` will be URL of repository

You can easy verify if, using TortoiseSVN's Repository Browser (if you see repo-tree in browser, URL is good), checkout code into local WC from some node of repository (from repo-browser), edit data and commit changes

Comment: I was able to access using the code using the browser but couldn't figure out how to commit new versions. I'll try again